# Importing plugins in Nuendo and Cubase

Tags: vst, cubase, plugins, importing, nuendo4

I am having trouble with importing VST plugins to Nuendo 4 and Cubase 5. I copied the `.dll` file, pasted it in the Steinberg plugins folder that came with the installation of the software, tried adding them again from Nuendo itself and clicked on `Update plugin information`, but my efforts failed to yield any fruit. I still can't find those plugins when I need to use them in my project.

Any help regarding this would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Cubase 5 is 11 years old, probably doesn't understand anything 64-bit or anything using VST3. As this is very likely to be an issue affecting only your machine, your best source for help would be either Steinberg or the plugin companies.

Comment: please specify more details: what version of the Windows and what plugins are already installed (32-and/or-64-bit)?